# find repeated element in list of list python

Tags: python, list, element

I have been struggling with this problem for two days and I need help with it. I need to find repeated element in a list of lists
`list_of_list = [(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2), ..., (an, bn, cn)]` where "a" and "b" elements are integers and "c" elements are floats.

So if for example `a1 == a2` or `a1 == bn`, I need to create a new list with the entire list elements and I need to iterate this for all the lists (a, b, c) in the list of lists. To put it another way, I need all lists that have elements that are present in more than one list. I need to compare only "a" and "b" elements but obtain the associated value "c" in the final list.

For example:

```
list_of_list = [(1, 2, 4.99), (3, 6, 5.99), (1, 4, 3.00), (5, 1, 1.12), (7, 8, 1.99) ]

desired_result=[(1, 2, 4.99), (1, 4, 3.00), (5, 1, 1.12)]
```

I try many ideas...but nothing nice came up:

```
MI_network = [] #repeated elements list
genesis = list(complete_net) #clon to work on
genesis_next = list(genesis) #clon to remove elements in iterations
genesis_next.remove(genesis_next[0])

while genesis_next != []:
    for x in genesis:
        if x[0] in genesis_next and x[1] not in genesis_next:
            MI_network.append(x)
        if x[0] not in genesis_next and x[1] in genesis_next:
            MI_network.append(x)
    genesis_next.remove(genesis_next[0])
```

Comment: Does `desired_result` contain the full result, or just one part of it?

Comment: You need to compare only with `a1` value?

Comment: do you mean `ai = aj` and `ai = bj` for i, j in (1, n) ?

Comment: 1-desired result have the full result
2- i need to compare all a elements with all a and b elements in all list

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using your idea, you can try this:

```
MI_network = []
complete_net = [(1, 2, 4.99), (3, 6, 5.99), (1, 4, 3.00), (5, 1, 1.12), (7, 8, 1.99)]
genesis = list(complete_net)

while genesis != []:
    for x in genesis:
        for gen in genesis:
            if x[0] in gen and x[1] not in gen:
                if x[0] != gen[2] and x[1] != gen[2]:
                    if x not in MI_network:
                        MI_network.append(x)
            elif x[0] not in gen and x[1] in gen:
                if x[0] != gen[2] and x[1] != gen[2]:
                    if x not in MI_network:
                        MI_network.append(x)
            elif x[0] not in gen and x[1] not in gen:
                pass
    genesis.remove(genesis[0])   

print(MI_network)
[(1, 2, 4.99), (1, 4, 3.0), (5, 1, 1.12)]
```

Answer (score -1):

And this is how i would do it since i was not aware of the `collections.defaultdict()`.

```
list_of_list = [(1, 2, 4.99), (3, 6, 5.99), (1, 4, 3.00), (5, 1, 1.12), (7, 8, 1.99) ]
results = []
for i_sub, subset in enumerate(list_of_list):
# test if ai == aj
    rest = list_of_list[:i_sub] + list_of_list[i_sub + 1:]
    if any(subset[0] == subrest[0] for subrest in rest):
        results.append(subset)
# test if ai == bj
    elif any(subset[0] == subrest[1] for subrest in rest):
        results.append(subset)
# test if bi == aj
    elif any(subset[1] == subrest[0] for subrest in rest):
        results.append(subset)
print(results)  # -> [(1, 2, 4.99), (1, 4, 3.0), (5, 1, 1.12)]
```

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to "broke" this code because i do not understand it at 100%, but by the moment it works really fine.

Comment: I compare this approach with @nicost and both gave me different results. Although nicost give me a list that is duplicated but this script do not detect such list.